# Is this supposed to happen?

Tags: updates, screen, restart

I am still new to Ubuntu, so excuse me if this is common. I am not familiar with what happened. I just got an "update" screen I have not seen before. It appeared before the logging in screen. It was Similar to the screen Windows shows while doing updates that need reset. "preparing update" or something like that. I only remember well that there were some updates. When I was going to restart the machine a message popped up with something about pending updates or reset and update. I restarted anyways. That black screen with the update thing appeared after the restart, it finished, the computer restart by itself and everything looks normal so far. Is that supposed to happen? I have never seen that update screen before.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Is this during a first time install?

Comment: Sounds like you just had your first automatic firmware upgrade 

Comment: @David It is Ubuntu 20.10. And no, It has already been a couple of months since I installed it.